# This website is using a scripted window error in ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer stops the scripts to run.

How to allow javascript codes to run without showing this `"This website is using a scripted window"` in internet explorer?

Help me in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to use `prompt()`? If so, there's a setting in Internet Options to allow pages to use scripted windows to prompt for information.

You should't rely on `prompt()` anyway, really. Use a form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your security settings in IE to allow JavaScript to run. The message is designed to warn users that JavaScript is being used. You can't disable this programmatically, since that would negate the whole purpose of the warning.

Comment: How to do this, please explain